# How to update page for all users

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

For example, i have page with comments. I want page update for all users watching that page,  every time someone adds comment. 
I can do it, using ajax update every few minutes. But there mast be a cleverer way, may be some java EE service is using for this purpose?

Comment: Why do you feel that sending the updates via Ajax is somehow unclever?  Sure you could mix a dose of JMS in the solution (best guess based on your description, using a Topic), and then use some webservice that transports the data to the clients.

Comment: @fvu: a server can't send anything to the browsers using Ajax. The browser must ask for updates.

Comment: @Vovan: you could use websockets, but they're not supported by every browser, and the current Java support is poor. Spring 4 has decent support, using stomp, which can downgrade to AJAX long polling in case websockets are not supported. But maybe all you need is periodic refreshes using AJAX, which consumes more bandwidth, and resources but will work everywhere.

Comment: @fvu, I thought about JMS. But HTTP protocol, by its nature, does not guarantee  that user is going to stay on current page for a long time. How do i know, when i should stop sending updates?
Nevertheless, i can see this functionality on many web-sites, including this one.

Comment: @JB Nizet, may be you are right..

Comment: @JBNizet I know that, that's why I used the word "transports" hoping that it would avoid the server takes initiative connotation...

Comment: @Vovan a couple of JMS related subjects that may help you shape a solution are the already mentioned topics, message lifetime and durable subscriptions.  ActiveMQ has [a number of features](http://activemq.apache.org/manage-durable-subscribers.html) that are helpful in a scenario like the one you describe.

Comment: You can use PrimeFaces Push, And take the common comment which you want to share between users into the ApplicationScoped ManagedBean. Then timely get value of that comment using PrimeFaces Push

Comment: Ok, PrimePush is the simplest solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look Server Push and Websocket examples, that are the terms to search for.

Comment: I found some framework, called [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere). PrimeFaces and RichFaces already use it.

Comment: then this is your way to go.